# Are questions about startup business ideas on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

The [on-topic help page](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) includes:

> - Best practices for saving for retirement, education, and other goals
> - Strategies for earning more money

Do other goals and strategies include startup business ideas?

For example, Can I ask a question to get ideas about a startup business that you can travel, help people and make money? The question might also ask for useful sources that list guidelines and consideration points.

How detailed should the question be?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, might be a dupe but I asked some specific questions also: http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/15/are-small-business-questions-on-topic

Comment: There is a [startups site](http://startups.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea: Thanks. I thought it was still in proposal stage. :)

Comment: Following up: looks like the latest Startups site has been closed due to insufficient activity.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I would comment on the on/off topic nature of startup questions generally, but I would say that the question as you described would not be a good StackExchange question regardless.  Questions designed to elicit discussion are the exact opposite of what a good question is; they should be questions that have a single answer, and are reasonably narrow in scope.  We also discourage "list" questions.  "What's a good XYZ" is usually a bad question.  See the [help center](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/help) for more information.

Now, I think that if you were to ask a narrowly focused question on that subject, it's possible, and it probably would get within range of being on-topic here if asked correctly.  But it would have to be narrowly focused, not just "I need some ideas", which is what your question reads like now.

> I'm thinking of semi-retiring, and going into business for myself.  I'm going to come up with an idea that will involve international travelling, offering some sort of personal service.  How do I need to prepare my finances for this?

That would be squarely on-topic, I think.  But eliciting ideas for what sort of service would not be.